# Expanding menu not responding

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to fix a mobile menu in a WordPress child theme (from Twentyseventeen) that is no longer expanding when 'menu' is clicked. Basically I've had to tear the header apart to move things around and now the aria expanded menu isn't recognised. Instead I'm trying to use javascript to change the display property of the ul from none to block, but this isn't working either - mostly because I don't know the first thing about js and I've just tried making something from bits and pieces of code.

The demo of the site is live at http://www.histeve.co.uk/testing/triangledrivertraining/

The javascript I'm trying to use is as follows:

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("topMenu");
document.getElementById("navBtn").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav() {
if( element.style.display == 'none' ) { 
function show() {('#topMenu').css ('display:block');}
} else {
function hide() {('#topMenu').css ('display:none'); }}
}
</script>
```

This is no longer kicking out errors, but it's not doing anything at all.

If anyone has any ideas, your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks
Steve

Comment: move the code outside of show function. if( element.style.display == 'none' ) { 
document.getElementById("topMenu").style.display="block";
} else {
document.getElementById("topMenu").style.display="none";
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var $topMenu = jQuery("#topMenu");
    jQuery("#navBtn").click(toggleNav);

    function toggleNav() {
        if($topMenu.is(":visible")) {
            $topMenu.hide();
        } else {
            $topMenu.show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

To always show the menu on desktop you should go with this solution:

Add following styles to your page:

```
 <style>
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .menu-navigation-container {
            display: none;
        }
        .menu-navigation-container.show-on-mobile {
            display: block;
        }
    }
</style>
```

Add use this JS:

```
<script>
    var $topMenu = jQuery(".menu-navigation-container");
    jQuery("#navBtn").click(function(){
        $topMenu.toggleClass("show-on-mobile");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry just one tiny thing, is there any way to reset the menu to show if the window is resized to full size? Unlikely a user will be resizing the screen all that much but now if I close it then maximise the window the menu stays hidden. I'm trying to fix with


    window.setInterval (function checkScreen() {
       if ( $(window).width() > 785) {
    $topMenu.show();
    }
    }, 1000);

Comment: I will write an extended solution in couple of minutes

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your both selector which should start with $ (since it is wordpress you might have to user jquery instead of $) as well as your css function as follows.

```
<script>
var element = document.getElementById("topMenu");
document.getElementById("navBtn").addEventListener("click", toggleNav);

function toggleNav() {
if( element.style.display == 'none' ) { 
function show() {$('#topMenu').css ('display','block');}
} else {
function hide() {$('#topMenu').css ('display','none'); }}
}
</script>
```

Alternative

Instead of using css you can toggle class which is much easier

```
function toggleNav() {
  $('#topMenu').toggleClass('active');
}
```

then in css

```
#topMenu{display: none;}

#topMenu.active{display: block;}
```